# No response in Eclipse: File ->Import->Existing Projects into Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, import

I'm trying to import one of the GWT samples into Eclipse by following the instructions below. But when I browse to the directory containing the "Hello" sample and uncheck "Copy projects into workspace", the Finish button is grayed out, preventing me from completing the import. Any ideas why?

> -- Option A: Import your project into Eclipse (recommended) --
>
> If you use Eclipse, you can simply
>   import the generated project into
>   Eclipse. We've tested against Eclipse
>   3.3 and 3.4.  Later versions will likely also work, earlier versions may
>   not.
>
> In Eclipse, go to the File menu and
>   choose:
>
> File -> Import... -> Existing
>   Projects into Workspace
>
> Browse to the directory containing
>   this file,   select "Hello".
>        Be sure to uncheck "Copy projects into workspace" if it is checked.
>        Click Finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem but found [this](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/da884d3bcd5c950d/67ad4c450d8824d1?lnk=raot):

> I just tried this on Eclipse 3.4 1)
>   Create a project named "Showcase"
>        file > new > project
>
> 2) Import the Showcase files
>        right-click on the project name
>
> > Import
> >     File System
> >     From Directory (browse to your eclipse samples installation)
> >     Showcase (select the directory in the left panel)
> >     Into folder (Showcase should be the default value)
>
> This will import the source into your
>   workspace. Use build.xml to build the
>   project. The build will fail as the
>   gwt-servlet.jar is in a shared
>   directory which doesn't get brought
>   into the project via this method.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this problem but got through it using following steps.

First open up a command prompt and go inside to the project folder using cd command.

then execute this command in there. Be sure to install apache ant before doing this.

```
ant eclipse.generate
```

this will generate .classpath and .project files

now you can import the project into the workspace just as normal way. file->import->general->existing project

Answer (score 0):

To import the samples from the Android SDK into Eclipse, do the following:

1. Click File->New->New Android Project
2. Select 'Create project from existing sample'
3. Select your Build Target (The Android API level)
4. Select the sample app you want.
5. Finish.

This is valid for Eclipse 3.5.2.

BTW: Link in previous answer is broken.

Answer (score -1):

after importing right click on the project ->Goolge->web toolkit setting->click yes the check box
and then run as a web application!

Comment: -1, OPs problem states that he cannot complete import itself.